# Refresh Token automatically when 401

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to implement a automatic refresh token and I'm seeing at least two ways of doing it, one is creating an `Interceptor` just to check if the status code is 401 then if it's 401 call the new service and chain the last call and other is something I've been reading days ago but I don't know if it's the optimal solution, is to use [`Authenticator - OkHttp3`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html).

I also have another question and is about cleaning architecture and don't depend of too much things, I mean having this Interceptor/Authenticator I'll have to have a dependency of my `SharedPreferences` to get the RefreshToken and also a dependency of a `RefreshTokenApiService` (it should only be on that class, so I don't know if I'd call a dependency), and also, somehow I have to log out the user in case the refresh token api call fails, so I'd need something like a `flow` or listener somewhere to listen that changes and logout the user and open Login, right?

The problem is if I do a login with an invalid credentials I got 401 too, so do I have to create two OkHttp? One for the validated users and one for the "Anonymous" users?